# Single USB Speaker with Built-in Sound Card and Microphone

Tags: usb, audio, speakers, microphones

I'd like to purchase several inexpensive USB-Speaker-Microphone-Combo-Devices for all the computers at our work place.

**Requirements:**

- Single Speaker - The device should have only one speaker that plays
  both right and left channels (not two speakers). It can have two speakers as long as they are built into one housing.
- Small - Must not take up much space (would like it to sit at the base
  of the computer's monitor for example)
- Built-in sound card - Should not require the computer to have its own
  sound card.
- USB Powered - Must get is power from USB exclusively.
- Built-in microphone - Would like users to be able to have VOIP calls 
  or audio chats via Google Voice or any other program that simply
  needs a speaker and microphone to function.

Any suggestions?